# Парсинг argc argv в бесконечном цикле

Tags: c

как правильно парсить argc i argv в языке С.
Делаю консольное приложение(что-то типа баша) и хочу парсить аргументы в бесконечном цыкле. 
Не могу разобратся как правильно это сделать и разбить аргументы на отдельные части(знаю о strtok, но к сожалению не работает иммено сдесь, возможно не правильно использую) чтобы вызывать команду, например exec.

К сожалению поделится кодом не могу, так как лаба будет проверятся на атиплагиат

Comment: `for (int i = 1; i < argc; i++) { puts(argv[i]);  // напечатать а затем обработать i-ый аргумент, если нумеровать их с 1 }`.  `argv[0]` это имя программы (начните печатать, дальше сами поймете) (и настоятельно советую [прочесть все это](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Program-Arguments.html#Program-Arguments) и разобраться)

Answer (score 0):

Для работы с аргументами командной строки, в стандартной библиотеке С, существует специальная функция *getopt()*:

> Функция getopt() разбирает аргументы командной строки. Её аргументы 
>   argc  и  argv  являются счётчиком  и  массивом  аргументов, которые
>   передаются функции main() при запуске программы.
>
> Элемент argv, начинающийся с «-» (и не  являющийся  «-»  или  «--»), 
>   считается  параметром. Символы  этого  элемента (не считая начального
>   «-») являются символами параметра. При каждом повторном вызове
>   getopt() возвращают следующий символ параметра и так для каждого
>   следующего параметра.

Если Вы посмотрите *man 3 getopt*, то там есть пример использования:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int
main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
   int flags, opt;
   int nsecs, tfnd;

   nsecs = 0;
   tfnd = 0;
   flags = 0;
   while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "nt:")) != -1) {
       switch (opt) {
       case 'n':
           flags = 1;
           break;
       case 't':
           nsecs = atoi(optarg);
           tfnd = 1;
           break;
       default: /* '?' */
           fprintf(stderr, "Использование: %s [-t nsecs] [-n] имя\n",
                   argv[0]);
           exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
       }
   }

   printf("flags=%d; tfnd=%d; nsecs=%d; optind=%d\n",
           flags, tfnd, nsecs, optind);

   if (optind >= argc) {
       fprintf(stderr, "После параметра требуется значение\n");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }

   printf("параметр = %s\n", argv[optind]);

   /* остальной код не показан */

   exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```

Существует более современный вариант этой функции - *getopt_long()*.

Comment: getopt не входит в стандартную библиотеку C